Tooltip background colour getting removed after initial hover #amcharts5
I'm working with amcharts5. Implementing a world map for my site.
The tooltip background colour getting removed after initial hover.
And after refresh comes back for a single time.
This is happening
This is what expected
Below is the code :
this.imageSeries.bullets.push(() => {
            if (this.root) {
                return am5.Bullet.new(this.root, {
                    sprite: am5.Picture.new(this.root, {
                        width: 20,
                        height: 30,
                        centerX: am5.p50,
                        centerY: am5.p100,
                        scale: 1,
                        templateField: "image",
                        tooltipText: "{title} \n {address}",
                        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root, {
                            background: am5.PointedRectangle.new(this.root, {
                                fill: am5.color("#000")
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        })

On hover the background color should remain intact
